# react useEffect is not getting called in chrome extension app when extension is opened

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, use-effect

I just started with react and chrome extension. I am creating an extension using **reactjs**

I have a `Home` component in which I am using `useEffect` hook, expecting to be called whenever component will be loaded.

code

```
  useEffect(() => {
    onLoad();
  }, []);

  function onLoad() {
    console.log("loading");
    const userLoggedIn = AuthService.isUserLoggedIn();
    if (!userLoggedIn) {
      console.log("User not logged in");
      props.history.push("/login");
      window.location.reload();
    }
  }
```

but this is not working in extension. Is extension not reloading the component when i open the extension? is there any solution for this..

Comment: Use devtools to debug it. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: i tried adding breakpoints.. but now when i close and open the extension again .. dev tool that i opened using inspect... got closed... so no breakpoint at all.. any solution?

Comment: Don't close it, but just press Ctrl-R or F5 inside devtools.

Comment: did you find the solution? I'm facing the same problem